# Center Bootstrap form-group input field and make it smaller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to implement the design you see below:

[image]

Everything is working except for the size of the input field and the button. I'm using Boostrap.

HTML:

```
  <div className='jumbotron text-center'>
    <div className='container'>
      <h1 id='hero-questions-h1'>What’s your name?</h1>
    </div>

    <div className='container'>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
        <div className="form-group input-group-lg">
          <input type="text" className="form-control"></input>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="continue-btn" className="btn btn-success btn-block">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div className='container'>
        <h2 id='tip'>
          Tip! You will get motivational playlists, stories, posters and much more
        </h2>
      </div>

    <footer className="footer">
      <div className="container">
        <p id="social-proof" className="text-center">“Must have for every ambitious athlete!”</p>
        <p id="social-proof-tagline" className="text-center">Anders Hasselstrøm, Deca Ironman (10x)</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
  background-image: url("bg-hero-v2.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

#hero-h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

#hero-h2 {
  color: #ECECEC;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#hero-questions-h1 {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 60px;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.btn-success {
  background-color: #66B878 !important;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: white !important;
}

#signup-btn {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#continue-btn {
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#social-proof {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
}

#social-proof-tagline {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#tip {
  color: #ECECEC;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.footer {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.6;

}
```

As you can see my current implementation looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM Elements use `class` instead of `className` to allocate CSS classes (You may have this confused with the JS [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property). To position the fields how you'd like, i would suggest taking advantage of the bootstrap grid [`col-x-offset-x` options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) to position the column offset from the left side of the `.row`

For correct positioning, remember to place a `.row` element around your columns, and between the `.container`. Also, `input` elements are self-closing (ie. you dont need the trailing `</input>`)

**HTML**

```
<div class='jumbotron text-center'>
    <div class='container'>
        <h1 id='hero-questions-h1'>What’s your name?</h1>
    </div>

    <div class='container'>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 text-center">
                <div class="form-group input-group-lg">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <button type="button" id="continue-btn" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class='container'>
        <h2 id='tip'>
          Tip! You will get motivational playlists, stories, posters and much more
        </h2>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p id="social-proof" class="text-center">“Must have for every ambitious athlete!”</p>
            <p id="social-proof-tagline" class="text-center">Anders Hasselstrøm, Deca Ironman (10x)</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xnc7dyg1/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for your input @haxxxton. Using className because it's inside a React component. I see your JSFiddle works, but using your code doesn't fix it on my end. Any idea of what could be wrong?

Comment: I have another question @haxxxton. You see the 'back arrow' in the top left corner? That's what I'm currently trying to implement without success. I'm trying to add a navbar in bootstrap but it becomes a fixed container in the top pushing down the jumbotron background image. 

Do you have an idea for a fix?

Comment: inside the `.jumbotron` element add a div with an id like `backButton` and then using CSS `position:absolute` that sucker into the top left hand corner :)

Answer (score 0):

I was just working with bootstrap now and I had the same problem. In place of:

```
<div className='container'>
  <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <div className="form-group input-group-lg">
      <input type="text" className="form-control"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="continue-btn" className="btn btn-success btn-block">Continue</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this:

```
<div className='container'>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
    <div className="form-group input-group-lg">
        <input type="text" className="form-control"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="continue-btn" className="btn btn-success btn-block">Continue</button>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

The extra class with `col-sm-4` will structure the divs in the correct order.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

The `&nbsp;` is optional but I found that it helped me.